# Get ASSOC array with PDO without using prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo, associative-array

I'm using an internal switch to determine the sort order of my results and have just discovered that you can't use `PDO` to bind certain params (like selecting a table or specifying a sort order) in this way.

So I'm now trying to return my results without binding using `->query` like this (ignoring the sort part for now) :

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * from tracks WHERE online = 1", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But when I `print_r($results)` I'm just getting the PDO object statement back :

```
PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => SELECT * from tracks WHERE online = 1
)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my PDO connection :

```
protected static function getDB()
    {

        static $db = null;

        if ($db === null) {
            $dbhost = getenv('DB_HOST');
            $dbuser = getenv('DB_USER');
            $dbpass = getenv('DB_PASS');
            $dbname = getenv('DB_NAME');

            try {
                $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8mb4",
                               $dbuser, $dbpass);

                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        return $db;
    }
```

Comment: What is `$db`? Instance of `PDO`?

Comment: Yes it's a PDO instance called statically

Comment: What is said in a manual? "`PDO::query()` returns a PDOStatement object"

Comment: Ahh it's okay I found the answer. I wasn't fetching anything. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the statement needs to be executed ...

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * from tracks WHERE online = 1");
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

passing it as second argument should also work:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * from tracks WHERE online = 1", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

or as one-liner:

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT * from tracks WHERE online = 1")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

there's also:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: No, it is not. `query` __can also be used__ to fetch results.

Comment: Martin is correct. I wasn't actually fetching anything. That's what trying to follow the examples on PHP.net will do for you. :/

Comment: the example uses `->query()` now... which nevertheless returns a statement.

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::query` [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php#refsect1-pdo.query-examples) shows you how to work with results, returned by `query` method:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * from tracks WHERE online = 1", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($results as $row) {
    print $row;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but that's nasty. I need to manipulate the entire array (which is multi-dimensional too). `$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` is way tidier.